# How can you display individual discounts in the cart?

Tags: cart, discount, rules

By default Magento totals up any discounts in the cart. I have a scenario where I would like to show 2 (or more) discounts that can be applied, but unfortunately they are totaled up.

Example:

Discount 1: 10$

Discount 2: 1.00$

Discount 3: 2.00$

Currently displays as:

Discount 1, Discount 2, Discount 3: 13$

How can I modify the template or override this default behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how we did this in [our module](http://amasty.com/special-promotions.html):

1) Add an observer, like this:

```
      <salesrule_validator_process>
        <observers>
            <amasty_rules_model_observer>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>amrules/observer</class>
                <method>handleValidation</method>
            </amasty_rules_model_observer>
        </observers>
        </salesrule_validator_process>
```

2) Remember all discounts:

```
public function process($observer)
{

    $amountToDisplay = $observer->getEvent()->getResult()->getDiscountAmount();
    $address = $observer->getEvent()->getAddress();
    $rule = $observer->getEvent()->getRule();

    // here we remember all info by address
    $this->_addFullDescription($address, $rule, $amountToDisplay);
    .....
}
```

3) inside _addFullDescription

```
    $descr = $address->getFullDescr();
    if (!is_array($descr)) {
        $descr = array();
    }
    $ruleLabel = $rule->getName();
    $descr[$rule->getId()] = array('label' => '<strong>' . htmlspecialchars($ruleLabel) . '</strong>', 'amount' => 0);
    $descr[$rule->getId()]['amount'] += $discount;
    $address->setFullDescr($descr);
```

4) and finally modify the template:

```
    <?php if (is_array($this->getTotal()->getFullInfo())) : ?>
    <?php foreach ($this->getTotal()->getFullInfo() as $info): ?>
            <td class="a-right" colspan="<?php echo $this->getColspan(); ?>">
                <?php echo $info['label']; ?>
                <br />
            </td>
            <td class="a-right" rowspan="1">
                -<?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($info['amount']); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```